# Will adoption of SMuFL change Lilypond's text input?

Tags: lilypond, transcription

On a [Lilypond page](https://lilypond.org/google-summer-of-code.html) under the section, "Adopt the [SMuFL](https://www.smufl.org) music font encoding standard" section, there were plans to transition to the SMuFL format which may become part of a W3C standard.

Would this change anything about Lilypond input files used to produce Lilypond output files?

For example, here is some code I found on the website which produces various notes using a treble clef:

```
{
  c' e' g' e'
}
```

Would code like this need to be changed, if SMuFL were to be adopted or would the adoption be a purely something that happens without end users noticing anything?

Comment: I don't know for certain, but I'm sure the intent is for end users to be unaware of any changes. LilyPond has years of history with their text-input syntax, and changing this input would only serve to frustrate and disenfranchise a pretty loyal user base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for posterity's sake, I wanted to highlight the lilypond-user listserv response to OP's question when they asked it there. (You can find the thread [here](https://mail.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-user/2021-02/msg00192.html).)

> SMuFL support would not change input syntax. It is about allowing the
> use of many alternative music notation fonts that follow this
> standard.
>
> There was a blog post on Scores of Beauty explaining the project;
> unfortunately that website is down at the moment. Meanwhile, you can
> read
>
> lilypond.org/google-summer-of-code.html